# Display Leaflet marker using latitude and longitude from XAMPP database using Laravel framework

Tags: javascript, laravel, leaflet, xampp

I need help with this problem since I tried quite a few tutorials and videos, but I still can't implement them.
[The homepage of my website including the Leaflet map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J0e7.jpg)
I intend to use the coordinates from my table in my xampp database, create a marker and display it on the map.

Here is my homepage HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>HelpThePoor</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={{url('css/main.css')}}>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
          integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
          crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
            crossorigin=""></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">



    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
        /*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */html{line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}a{background-color:transparent}[hidden]{display:none}html{font-family:system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,Noto Sans,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol,Noto Color Emoji;line-height:1.5}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box;border:0 solid #e2e8f0}a{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit}svg,video{display:block;vertical-align:middle}video{max-width:100%;height:auto}.bg-white{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#fff;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,var(--bg-opacity))}.bg-gray-100{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#f7fafc;background-color:rgba(247,250,252,var(--bg-opacity))}.border-gray-200{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#edf2f7;border-color:rgba(237,242,247,var(--border-opacity))}.border-t{border-top-width:1px}.flex{display:flex}.grid{display:grid}.hidden{display:none}.items-center{align-items:center}.justify-center{justify-content:center}.font-semibold{font-weight:600}.h-5{height:1.25rem}.h-8{height:2rem}.h-16{height:4rem}.text-sm{font-size:.875rem}.text-lg{font-size:1.125rem}.leading-7{line-height:1.75rem}.mx-auto{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.ml-1{margin-left:.25rem}.mt-2{margin-top:.5rem}.mr-2{margin-right:.5rem}.ml-2{margin-left:.5rem}.mt-4{margin-top:1rem}.ml-4{margin-left:1rem}.mt-8{margin-top:2rem}.ml-12{margin-left:3rem}.-mt-px{margin-top:-1px}.max-w-6xl{max-width:72rem}.min-h-screen{min-height:100vh}.overflow-hidden{overflow:hidden}.p-6{padding:1.5rem}.py-4{padding-top:1rem;padding-bottom:1rem}.px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.pt-8{padding-top:2rem}.fixed{position:fixed}.relative{position:relative}.top-0{top:0}.right-0{right:0}.shadow{box-shadow:0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06)}.text-center{text-align:center}.text-gray-200{--text-opacity:1;color:#edf2f7;color:rgba(237,242,247,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-300{--text-opacity:1;color:#e2e8f0;color:rgba(226,232,240,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-400{--text-opacity:1;color:#cbd5e0;color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-500{--text-opacity:1;color:#a0aec0;color:rgba(160,174,192,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-600{--text-opacity:1;color:#718096;color:rgba(113,128,150,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-700{--text-opacity:1;color:#4a5568;color:rgba(74,85,104,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-900{--text-opacity:1;color:#1a202c;color:rgba(26,32,44,var(--text-opacity))}.underline{text-decoration:underline}.antialiased{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.w-5{width:1.25rem}.w-8{width:2rem}.w-auto{width:auto}.grid-cols-1{grid-template-columns:repeat(1,minmax(0,1fr))}@media (min-width:640px){.sm\:rounded-lg{border-radius:.5rem}.sm\:block{display:block}.sm\:items-center{align-items:center}.sm\:justify-start{justify-content:flex-start}.sm\:justify-between{justify-content:space-between}.sm\:h-20{height:5rem}.sm\:ml-0{margin-left:0}.sm\:px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.sm\:pt-0{padding-top:0}.sm\:text-left{text-align:left}.sm\:text-right{text-align:right}}@media (min-width:768px){.md\:border-t-0{border-top-width:0}.md\:border-l{border-left-width:1px}.md\:grid-cols-2{grid-template-columns:repeat(2,minmax(0,1fr))}}@media (min-width:1024px){.lg\:px-8{padding-left:2rem;padding-right:2rem}}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){.dark\:bg-gray-800{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#2d3748;background-color:rgba(45,55,72,var(--bg-opacity))}.dark\:bg-gray-900{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#1a202c;background-color:rgba(26,32,44,var(--bg-opacity))}.dark\:border-gray-700{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#4a5568;border-color:rgba(74,85,104,var(--border-opacity))}.dark\:text-white{--text-opacity:1;color:#fff;color:rgba(255,255,255,var(--text-opacity))}.dark\:text-gray-400{--text-opacity:1;color:#cbd5e0;color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--text-opacity))}.dark\:text-gray-500{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:#6b7280;color:rgba(107,114,128,var(--tw-text-opacity))}}
    </style>

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="square">
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/" role="button">Kembali ke Menu Utama</a>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">Profil</a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class=" ">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h2>SOS Berhampiran</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="beneflist">
                <h3>Perlu Bantuan</h3>
                @foreach($beneficiary as $key => $data)
                    <div class="helpsquare">
                        <b style="font-size: 25px">{{$data->name}}</b><br>
                        {{$data->help_needed}}<br>
                        Jenis Bantuan: <b style="font-size: 20px">{{$data->help_type}}</b>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <div class="beneflist">
                <h3>Mahu Membantu</h3>
                @foreach($donor as $key => $data)
                    <div class="helpsquare">
                        <b style="font-size: 25px">{{$data->name}}</b><br>
                        {{$data->help_offered}}<br>
                        Jenis Bantuan: <b style="font-size: 20px">{{$data->help_type}}</b><br>
                        <a href=" " type="buttons" class="btn btn-success">Lihat Bantuan</a>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="map">
        <div class="btn-group" style="z-index: 1001; margin: 0;position: absolute;top: 92%; left: 40%; -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);transform: translateY(-50%);"> <!-- Use 401 to be between map and controls -->
            <a class="btn btn-DANGER btn-lg btn-block" href="benef_form" role="button" style="color: white">SAYA PERLU BANTUAN!</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script
        src="{{url('js/map.js')}}">
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here's the [database table 'Beneficiary'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dygc8.png)

and here's the current map.js

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([1.465036, 830.428012], 15);
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGFuaWVscmFjaGV2YXNraSIsImEiOiJjbDFlZzBpN2wwcjE1M2ZuNHF3NXRvbGh5In0.U44yx8ueWFpYviMcI1U1Sw'
}).addTo(map);

//var marker = L.marker([1.469607, 830.42104]).addTo(map);
//marker.bindPopup("<b>Saya memerlukan</b><br>makanan").openPopup();

//var marker = L.marker([1.469607, 830.42104]).addTo(map);

function onMapClick(e) {
    alert("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng);
}
map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a js array populated with your data like so:

```
    const beneficiary = [
        [1.1, 832, "anonymous"],
        [null, null, "Nurkaki"],
        [1.4666, 830.43, "Anwar Ibrahin"]
    ];
```

Granted your data base connection is working your laravel foreach loop should work like this:

```
const beneficiary = [
    @foreach($beneficiary as $key => $data)
        [ "{{$data->lat}}", "{{$data->lng}}", "{{$data->name}}" ],
    @endforeach
];
```

You could add this in a `<script>` tag to your html body before initializing leaflet.

**Static example**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:60vh"></div>

<script>
  const beneficiary = [
    [1.1, 832, "anonymous"],
    [null, null, "Nurkaki"],
    [1.4666, 830.43, "Anwar Ibrahin"]
  ];
</script>

<!-- content of map.js -->
<script>
  //init map
  let map = L.map('map').setView([1.469607, 830.42104], 8);
  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
  }).addTo(map);

  //add markers
  if (beneficiary.length) {
    beneficiary.forEach(function(data, i) {
      let [lat, lng] = [data[0], data[1]];
      let label = data[2];
      if (lat && lng) {
        marker = new L.marker([lat, lng])
          .bindPopup(label)
          .addTo(map);

      } else {
        console.log('no geo data available for: ' + label)
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```

You should also check if your data item contains any lat/lng and skip these items.

Comment: THANKS! it works in my website now.
I don't know, but I added double quotation marks to the datas as this:

`const beneficiary = [`
               `@foreach($beneficiary as $key => $data)`
            `[ "{{$data->lat}}" , "{{$data->lng}}" , "{{$data->name}}"],`
            `@endforeach`
        `];`
and the markers are shown on the map. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Danny Rachevaski:  Fixed the laravel code snippet. BTW: depending on the total amount of markers you might also use a [marker cluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) - this will group nearby markers when zooming out.